# SQL Match City Name Inside Full Address?

Tags: sql, database

How would you list the people from a database that are not from 'London'?
Say the database is:

```
Cust_id         address
  1             33 avenue, Liverpool
  2             21 street 12345, London 
  3             469 connection ave, Manchester
```

I'd like to list the customers that are NOT from London. Here's what I've tried:

```
select Cust_id from customers where address <> 'London';
```

Now when I do that, it lists all the customers, regardless of location.

Help would be greatly appericated.

Comment: In your column, `London` only the part of row value, and row value is `33 avenue, Liverpool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not ideal but might satisfy your requirements:

```
 select Cust_id from customers 
 where address NOT LIKE '% London%';
```

[Note the added space: it assumes you will always precede the city name with a space. `'%London%'` would match words containing London]

(It might be better if you had a normalised address, i.e. broken into street address, town, city, etc.))

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much! I'll choose this as best answer in 10 mins once it allows me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`select Cust_id from customers where address not like '%London%';`

or this:

`select Cust_id from customers where not address like '%London%';`

Both of these are OK.

For more details on `LIKE` see e.g. here: [SQL LIKE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Although I prefer `not like` to `not . . . like`, your answer was first, so deserves to be upvoted.